# huge inserts, no updates, moderate reads with billions of rows datastore

Tags: datastore, nosql

Our system need 10 million inserts per day(structural data), storage upto 3 months(which adds up to 300 million records, after which we can purge older records), no updates are required, and it should support simple queries(like queries on some particular columns sorted by date). Which data storage solution is efficient for this case?. We are thinking RDBMS will be slow for billions of records.

Answer (score 0):

MySql might work, if you can optimize the way you insert.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

Of course it depends if your 1M inserts are evenly spread or you have picks.

If you have picks of very height TPS I would recommend [aerospike](http://www.aerospike.com/).

[MongoDb](https://docs.mongodb.com/) can also work, however you will need to use sharding.

Comment: In 3 months data will cross billion mark, will mysql perform well on queries at this point of time?, also why do we need a transactional database in case we dont need updates?

Comment: A strong server can handle it if your inserts are spread evenly.I do not know your needs transactions might be important for inserts too. With very big tables Mongodb  gives a great performance benefit only if you use sharding.